# cannot connect to in-memory SQLite DB using SQLAlchemy with Python 2.7.3 on Windows

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use the in-memory SQLite database using SQLAlchemy with Python 2.7.3 on Windows. I can connect to the engine, but when I try to execute the second statement I am getting the following error:

```
>>>    engine=create_engine('sqlite:///memory:',echo=True)
>>>    engine.execute("select 1").scalar()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2445, in execute
connection = self.contextual_connect(close_with_result=True)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2489, in contextual_connect
self.pool.connect(),
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 236, in connect
return _ConnectionFairy(self).checkout()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 401, in __init__
rec = self._connection_record = pool._do_get()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 822, in _do_get
return self._create_connection()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 189, in _create_connection
return _ConnectionRecord(self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 282, in __init__
self.connection = self.__connect()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 344, in __connect
connection = self.__pool._creator()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 80, in connect
return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 281, in connect
return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) unable to open database file
None None
```

Answer (score 25):

The filename should be `:memory:`, not `memory:`. (See [the docs for in-memory databases](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html)). The [relevant SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/dialects/sqlite.html#connect-strings) mention that's the default path, so you should use:

```
engine=create_engine('sqlite://',echo=True)
```

The error you're getting is presumably because `memory:` isn't a valid filename on Windows.

Comment: this aint working...n i am just new on sqlalchemy so i wanted to know that whether the database sqlite has to be installed separately or does it comes inbuilt with the sqlalchemy package.If i have to install sqlite separately then where should i instaal it .You know give me info on the configuration.

Comment: @user1742141 `sqlite` comes with every Python installation, you shouldn't need to deal with this.

Comment: @user1742141 See if you can just `import sqlite3` in a console?

Comment: @user1742141 I just tried your code with the fix from my answer on a clean-ish Python install under Windows and it works. Are you sure you're not using three slashes (`///`) instead of two (`//`)?

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.pool import StaticPool

engine = create_engine("sqlite://", poolclass=StaticPool)
```